# unexpected value in php using `+` for strings

Tags: php, file-exists

I´m using this script:

```
<object data="<?php echo basename(__FILE__, ".php"); ?>.svg"></object>
```

Now I want to add another line like:

```
<?php if (file_exists(basename(__FILE__, ".php") + "b.svg")) { ?>
    <object data="<?php echo basename(__FILE__, ".php"); ?>b.svg"></object>
<?php } ?>
```

This code does not work, the `if` is never true. I checked the code I'm passing in: `basename(__FILE__, ".php") + "b.svg")`. The value is `page1`. But I would expect to get `page1b.svg`. Why do I get `page1` as value ?

Comment: You are trying to concatenate strings with `+`. In PHP, the operator for that is `.`. Please go and **read the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)**.

Comment: hahahaha okay fair enough

Comment: @hek2mgl I don't think rewording will help to open this question right ? Shall I delete it ?

Comment: Would there be a reason to reopen it? But if you want to improve it, then a) fix the title which is horribly misleading and screams newbie or worse from miles away (what is more likely: that `file_exists` does not work or that you are doing something wrong?) and b) show some troubleshooting effort on your part, *anything*. For example, `file_exists` obviously returns an unexpected result. Did you actually check what is the value you are passing in? Show that you did. Saying "the value was X while I expected Y, why?" would be a much better question.

Comment: @Jon It's not that I don't have a good answer yet. The problem is, after asking this question I'm not able to post questions anymore on stackoverflow. Thanks for helping me, I tried to improve the question. I understand that this question is too localized, and I don't think my edit will make it less localized. I just hope that some downvotes will be removed so I can ask new questions again.

Comment: Great, this question is *much* better than the first version and is certainly not "too localized" anymore (the confusion between `+` and `.` applies to potentially everyone, while "why does this code not work" did not). FYI, there have been [very recent changes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/) to the site and now "too localized" is not a thing anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php if (file_exists(basename(__FILE__, ".php") . "b.svg")) { ?>
```

replace `+` with `.`

Comment: thanks anyway, I know, it's bad to just assume programming languages have kind of the same syntax :p

Comment: Yes. It is especially confusing when you switch between javascript and PHP, etc. No worries :)

Comment: I totally forgot, sorry. It was helpfull. I have a little bitter taste in my mouth of this question tough, as since I asked this question, I got banned for asking any new question at stackoverflow ;(

Comment: @Kasper I understand. While StackOverflow is a very helpful community,  it could get a little too strict at times considering the number of users and the questions that get asked. Moving forward, i wish that you have a great experience though